# se puede convertir un String en una lista Date en java?

Tags: java, jsf, date

Dentro de mi clase, tengo el siguiente metodo

```html
public void buscaDetalleIncidencia() {
        System.out.println("ENTRO AL METODO BUSCA DETALLE POR AÑO/MESSS");

        muestraTablaDetalle = true;

        incidenciaAnioMesDet = anioMesDetService.findIncidenciaAnioMesDeByAnioMes(cvePersona, annio, mes);
        
        System.out.println("INCIDENCIA\n" + "DIA-" +incidenciaAnioMesDet.get(0).getDia() + " MES-" +incidenciaAnioMesDet.get(0).getIncidenciaAnioMes().getMes() + " AÑO-" +incidenciaAnioMesDet.get(0).getIncidenciaAnioMes().getAnio() +" CVE INCIDENCIA-" +incidenciaAnioMesDet.get(0).getIncidencias().getCveIdIncidencia());

        //PRUEBA LISTA
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.clear();
        calendar.set(annio, mes - 1, 1);

        while (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == mes - 1) {
            fechas.add(calendar.getTime());
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        }

        System.out.println("PREBA LISTA FECHA" + fechas);

    }
```

donde a mi lista incidenciaAnioMesDet  le paso el find que me devuelve lo siguiente en consola

INCIDENCIA
DIA-1 MES-3 AÑO-2018 CVE INCIDENCIA-12

ahora ese dato, es el que debo de pintar en mi tabla, en la columna incidencia el 12, sobre la fila correspondiente a la columna fecha 01/02/2018

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que relacion tiene cada detalle con un dia en particular? como sabes a que dia corresponde un detalle?

Comment: @Klaimmore, la lista con la que lleno la tabla le paso un find,  incidenciaAnioMesDet = anioMesDetService.findIncidenciaAnioMesDeByAnioMes(cvePersona, annio, mes);  y eso me regresa un listado de incidencias que tuvo una persona en en una fecha en especifico

Comment: En un año y mes especificos, pero en que dia? de ese listado como sabes cual le corresponde a cual dia?

Comment: horaEntrada y horaSalida son 2 objetos dates que contienen la fecha y hora? si es asi entonces deberias simplemente formatear uno de ellos mostrando solo el dd/MM/yyyy en la primera columna

Comment: @Klaimmore, ese find tambien me arrojaa el dia, el año, el mes y el incidente, el objetivo de esa tabla, es mostrar todos los dias del mes, y hacer el match con el incidente, si tuve un incidente 9 el dia de hoy, entonces en mi tabla, en la fecha de hoy , en el campo de incidencia debe mostrar el 9

Comment: Y si hay mas de un incidente el mismo dia?

Comment: @Klaimmore, solamente es una

Comment: la primer fecha cual es, es date? como la obtienes, porque veo que la conviertes a String y luego la pareseas a date

Comment: entonces el datatable deberia recibir el listado de todos los dias del mes y no un listado de incidentes. Y a partir de un dia del mes obtener el incidente relacionado para llenar las demas columnas.

Comment: @Klaimmore, ya cambie mi listado de los dias en la tabla, como mencionas, pero lo unico que hace  es mostrarme todas las filas del los dias del mes, pero como pinto la fecha?

Comment: la variable que debe llevar la fecha (creo que es 1Dias) debe estar dentro del for, y el for dentro del try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que construir un listado de Date a partir de tu mes y año. Un ejemplo de implementacion usando Calendar a continuacion:

```
/**
 *
 * @param mes 1 = Enero, 12 = Diciembre
 * @param anio
 * @return
 */
public static List<Date> crearFechas(int mes, int anio) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.clear();
    calendar.set(anio, mes - 1, 1);

    List<Date> fechas = new ArrayList<>();
    while (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == mes - 1) {
        fechas.add(calendar.getTime());
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    }
    return fechas;
}
```

Deberias tambien crear otra clase para asociar una fecha con su respectiva incidencia:

```
public class FechaIncidencia {
    private Date fecha;
    private Incidencia incidencia;

    public Date getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public Incidencia getIncidencia() {
        return incidencia;
    }

    public void setIncidencia(Incidencia incidencia) {
        this.incidencia = incidencia;
    }
}
```

Luego con tu lista de fechas del mes, crear un listado de `FechaIncidencia` con ambos objetos asociados:

```
public static List<FechaIncidencia> crearFechaIncidencia(List<Incidencia> incidenciaAnioMesDet, int mes, int anio) {
    List<Date> fechas = crearFechas(mes, anio);
    List<FechaIncidencia> fechasIncidencias = new ArrayList<>();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    for(Date fecha : fechas) {
        FechaIncidencia fechaIncidencia = new FechaIncidencia();
        fechaIncidencia.setFecha(fecha);
        calendar.setTime(fecha);
        for(Incidencia incidencia : incidenciaAnioMesDet) {
            if(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == incidencia.getDia()) {
                fechaIncidencia.setIncidencia(incidencia);
                break;
            }
        }
        fechasIncidencias.add(fechaIncidencia);
    }
    return fechasIncidencias;
}
```

Lo usarias en tu codigo de la siguiente forma:

```
incidenciaAnioMesDet = anioMesDetService.findIncidenciaAnioMesDeByAnioMes(cvePersona, annio, mes);
fechasIncidencias = crearFechaIncidencia(incidenciaAnioMesDet, mes, annio);
```

Por ultimo el listado de fechasIncidencias es lo que debes iterar en tu `<p:dataTable>`:

```
<p:dataTable id="detalle" var="detalle" styleClass="columns"
    value="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.fechasIncidencias}" emptyMessage="No se encontraron registros.">
...
<p:column styleClass="columns">
  <h:outputText value="#{detalle.fecha}">
    <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
  </h:outputText>
</p:column>
<p:column styleClass="columns">
  <h:outputText value="#{detalle.incidencia.horaEntrada}">
    <f:convertDateTime type="date" timeZone="CST" pattern="HH:mm:ss" />
  </h:outputText>
</p:column>
...
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: pero lo que se quiere es mostrar todas las fechas en el listado y solo muestra la primera. Para hacer eso se debe usar un for loop, dentro de el debe ir la variable que debe tener la fecha, y el for debe ir dentro del try

Comment: La iteración de fechas incidencia es tarea del dataTable

Comment: hola @Klaimmore, gracias por el aporte, implemente el metodo  para la lista de fechas en mi metodo init, y me muestra en consola PRUBA LISTA FECHA[Thu Mar 01 00:00:00 CST 2018, Fri Mar 02 00:00:00 CST 2018, Sat Mar 03 00:00:00 CST 2018, Sun Mar 04 00:00:00 CST 2018,n], ahora, esa lista fechas, la puse en el value de mi datatable, y me pinta todas las filas correspondientes al numero de mes

Comment: @Klaimmore, y en la columna fecha, puse en el value = detalle.day , para ver que se pintaba en esa columna y me sale esta fecha 01/01/1970 repetida en todas las filas

Comment: Edita tu pregunta con lo que llevas y pon la clase que estás usando para iterar el dataTable

Comment: @Klaimmore, ya agregue mi clase como respuesta

Comment: Tienes que editar tu pregunta en lugar de agregar una respuesta. Por lo que veo en el codigo que pusiste estas iterando `List<Date>` en tu `<p:dataTable>`, eso no te ayuda. Si quisieras mostrar solo las fechas, en lugar de mostrar `<h:outputText value="#{detalle.day}">` muestra `<h:outputText value="#{detalle}">`. Para para que realmente soluciones tu problema original debes crear un objeto como el que puse en mi respuesta `FechaIncidencia` para asociar una fecha a una incidencia y mostrarla en la misma fila.

Comment: @Klaimmore, ahorita solo queria ver que mostrara las fechas, muchas gracias, y si voy a hacer lo de fehaIncidencia, para mostrar la incidencia correspondiente al dia

Comment: @Klaimmore, ya edite mi pregunta,  es que veo que en el ejemplo que me pusiste creas dos objetos, pero entonces esos se los debo de pasar a mi lista incidenciaAnioMesDet?? es que es de esta lista donde obtengo el dato de la incidencia con la fecha a que corresponde

Comment: Pues tu debes determinar como asociar una fecha con su respectiva incidencia. Mencionaste que para 1 dia solo hay 1 incidencia.

Comment: @Klaimmore,  pero como le puedo hacer para hacer el match del dia de la incidencia con la lista de fechas?, la vdd apenas empiezo y me cuesta , no veo de que forma seria, gracias

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74318/discussion-between-klaimmore-and-root93).

Answer (score 0):

esta es mi clase

```html
   @Scope("session")
@Component("RegistroAccesoComponent")
public class RegistroAccesoComponentImpl extends BaseBean implements RegistroAccesoComponent, Serializable {


 private Integer annio;
    private Integer mes;
 private List<Date> fechas = new ArrayList<>();

//Metodo que inicializa
@Override
    public String newRegistroAcceso() {
 
 // Obtienes el mes actual
        mes = LocalDate.now().getMonth().getValue();
 
 //Se obtiene el año actual
        Year año = Year.now();
        annio = año.getValue();
  
  //PRUEBA LISTA
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.clear();
        calendar.set(annio, mes - 1, 1);

       
        while (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == mes - 1) {
            fechas.add(calendar.getTime());
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        }

        System.out.println("PREBA LISTA FECHA" + fechas);
 
 }



}
```

y esta mi tabla

```html
<p:dataTable id="detalle" var="detalle" styleClass="columns" value="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.fechas}" emptyMessage="No se encontraron registros.">

  <p:columnGroup type="header">
    <p:row>

      <p:column headerText="FECHA" style="width:20px;" styleClass="columns" />
      <p:column headerText="ENTRADA" style="width:20px;" styleClass="columns" />
      <p:column headerText="SALIDA" style="width:20px;" styleClass="columns" />
      <p:column headerText="INCIDENCIA" style="width:60px;" styleClass="columns" />
      <p:column headerText="ACCIÓN" style="width:10px;" styleClass="columns" />
    </p:row>
  </p:columnGroup>
  <p:column styleClass="columns">
    <h:outputText value="#{detalle.day}">
      <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
    </h:outputText>
  </p:column>

  <p:column styleClass="columns">
    <h:outputText>
      <f:convertDateTime type="date" timeZone="CST" pattern="HH:mm:ss" />
    </h:outputText>

  </p:column>
  <p:column styleClass="columns">
    <h:outputText>
      <f:convertDateTime type="date" timeZone="CST" pattern="HH:mm:ss" />
    </h:outputText>
  </p:column>
  <p:column styleClass="columns">
    <h:outputText />
  </p:column>
  <p:column styleClass="columns">
    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search" title="View" onclick="PF('modalIntentos').show();">
    </p:commandButton>
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

y lo que muestra
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]